# Mysql timediff returning two different values

Tags: php, mysql, select, time

I have one query that I'm testing times with.

I get two different times and this is making me doubt the correctness of my data.

Here are the two examples :

```
SELECT 
    users.fname as counselor,
    count(session.anum) as students,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(starttime, signintime)))) AS 'AVG Wait Time',
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(finishtime, starttime)))) AS 'AVG Session Length'
FROM session
    LEFT JOIN support 
        ON support.session_id = session.session_id
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.username = support.counselor
WHERE session.status = 3 
GROUP BY fname;
```

This returns :

```
00:01:17 and 00:00:05
```

the next query is :

```
SELECT 
    users.fname as counselor,
    count(session.anum) as students,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMEDIFF(starttime, signintime))) AS 'AVG Wait Time',
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMEDIFF(finishtime, starttime))) AS 'AVG Session Length'
FROM session
    LEFT JOIN support 
        ON support.session_id = session.session_id
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.username = support.counselor
WHERE session.status = 3 
GROUP BY fname;

00:01:37 and 00:00:05
```

Why does this happen and which result set am I supposed to trust? Would love if any one can clear my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIMEDIFF() returns a string, e.g.

```
TIMEDIFF('13:07:33', '9:5:37') -> 04:01:56
```

If you average that directly, mysql will try to cast `04:01:56` to an int and end up with `avg(04)` instead.

which is why you have to `time_to_sec`, which returns that time value as a simple int: 14516, which CAN be averaged directly.

Comment: Ah, so the TIME_TO_SEC version of the query is the most reliable? Would it be best to use TIMESTAMPDIFF() instead?

Comment: This is true. `AVG()` is used with an int. This takes all numbers that come before an non-number characters and removes everything after them. Example would be `123!456 -> 123`. Good job Marc.

Comment: While I wait to accept the answer, would it be best to use TIMESTAMPDIFF()

Comment: easiest method is `AVG(unix_timestamp(start) - unix_timestamp(end))`. that'll convert the datetimes DIRECTLY to plain "seconds" (ints).

Comment: Might seem like a stupid remark but would it be smart to use unix_timestamp / SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF()))) on all my time differences?

Comment: whatever does the least number of format conversions would be best. e.g. you're doing `datetime(timediff) -> time(timetosec) -> int(avg) -> time(sec_to_time)`. unixtimestamp would be `datetime -> int -> time`